# Macbook screen bottom half black

Tags: macbook-pro, display

[image]

The display shows up fine if I connect to an external display.

Is this a hardware problem that can only be fixed by replacing the entire screen? It's no longer on warranty (1.5 years, no AppleCare), and the customer support told me it'd cost $128 for a diagnose and $600-800 for replacement of screen, which I thought it'd be more worth just buying a new one.

Comment: It looks like a hardware problem to me. Have you tried running [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)?

Comment: You can see the broken bit, bottom right on the picture; the scratch might be a red herring, but the dark blob is a broken LCD.

Comment: Even if you do it your self, the parts will cost you $490  https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2015+Display+Assembly+Replacement/55925

Comment: @fsb can't do that because screen is completely black during the diagnosis. It doesn't project to my external monitors too, so I can't see anything.

Comment: If you can't run an external display then there's more broken than just the display  - you can still send it in approving the $400 cost or decide if you would repair this for $800 - I wouldn't do a self repair if this was a drop or damage - the battery mounts and logic board are likely damaged as well as the screen - it usually takes a hard fall to split the LCD like yours shows. Can you post a photo of any impact to the aluminum case or is it pristine due to being in another case or just didn't get dropped?

Comment: @bmike it can't connect to external display only during the diagnostic test (because I believe the test disables that functionality). It was dropped though strangely the problem only came few days after the drop.

Comment: Internally, the tolerances are so slim that a drop can take weeks or months to finally stress the board and components. As long as the case isn't physically damaged, there's hope for the $400 or less flat rate repair to fix everything internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put this in as an answer...

You can see the broken bit, bottom right on the picture; the scratch might be a red herring, but the dark blob is a broken LCD.

[image]

Comment: Great catch! Want me to add all my words to your answer or just let there be two answers here?

Comment: @bmike - I'm completely happy with either, or even drop my bit into yours [neither of use are desperate for the rep points ;). I'll let you make the call as to which will work best for the site overall.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no external damage to the case -  you’re hearing the worst case estimates. Internal screen damage like you have get repaired flat rate, mail in for less than $400 US as long as the external glass is OK and the case isn't damaged / bent showing a hard fall.

If you do have external damage due to a fall - they are preparing you for maybe paying more. If they can do the repair for less - Apple always charges less so even if they quote $800 it will charge $400 if that's all you need when you send it.

I would call back and get an understanding on the flat rate repair options and have them quote you that. This is almost certainly hardware failure. The reason it would go to 600 or 800 would be due to additional damage to the case (400 + 200) or case and screen and logic board (600 + 200).

If you like this mac, consider that any of the above repairs is cheaper than a new one. Hopefully it’s just an internal screen failure and yours qualifies for flat rate. I’ve never heard of Apple charging a diagnostic fee if you legitimately think you qualify for flat rate, send it in and then decline the more costly repair.

Don’t pay to diagnose it, just pay to repair once you’re sure it’s worth at least 400 to you once made as good as new. Same for the $800 - you get what's a totally rebuilt - new case, new computer tested and warranted by Apple for 90 days for $800 - way better than buying that model used on the internet. The only reason not to repair is you're looking for a different model. In that case find someone who wants a $400 or $800 Mac and gift / sell them yours knowing they have to pay to repair or use it with an external display in closed clamshell mode.